# Binomial Probability Distribution Model

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am practicing problem about binomial probability before the semester starts. The problem is like this:

> You flip a coin 10 times. You get 4 heads and 6 tails. What is the
>   probability of getting a head on your next flip.

If I understand this right, I just need to multiply p(4 heads and 6 tails) x probability of getting head on a single trial.

Which is:

10C4 x (1/2)^4 x (1/2)^6 x (1/2).

Is there any way to make sure the probability model I make is correct?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: The probability of getting head is independent from the past flips. Let $R$ denotes the result of the past 10 flips and $H$ denotes the event that the next flip is head. Then the following relation is true $P(H|R)=P(H)$ - due independency of $R$ and $H$.

Comment: I mean independence instead of independency.

Comment: Do you have any *other reason* to suspect that the coin is biased, other than obtaining slighty more tails than heads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your coin is fair, the answer is 50%. It has nothing to do with previous result.

Consider a different question: you flip a coin 11 times, what is the probability you have 5 heads and 6 tails. Here you should use the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

> If I understand this right, I just need to multiply p(4 heads and 6
>   tails) x probability of getting head on a single trial.

This is the **joint probability** of the two events "4 heads and 6 tails in first 10 tosses" AND "heads on 11th toss"

The question is asking for the **conditional probability** of getting heads given your first 10 tosses were 4 heads and 6 tails. Since your previous tosses have no effect on the outcome of your next toss, the probability of getting heads will be 0.5 (assuming a fair coin).